# Reschedule the task using ManagedScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a requirement to schedule the task which will run when the trigger fires. I'm using the `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` to schedule the task.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command,Trigger trigger)
```

Users will schedule multiple tasks, for eg:

1. user1 scheduled a task which will fire every day at 9pm.
2. user2 scheduled a task which will fire every day at 10pm.
3. user3 scheduled a task which will fire alternate days at 4pm

user2 want to reschedule a task to run every day at 10am. Now I want to cancel the previous task and create a new task. Storing the `ScheduledFuture` reference in memory doesn't work, as we are using the cluster environment. I can't store the reference of `ScheduledFuture` in the database as the `scheduledFuture` is not serialized.

How can I store the `scheduledFuture` reference or is there any way to reschedule the task?

```
ScheduledFuture future = managedScheduledExecutorService.schedule(task, triggerimpl);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have a method 
**SCHEDULE**

```
class Scheduler {
 private ScheduledFuture future;
    public void schedule (){
     future = managedScheduledExecutorService.schedule(task, triggerimpl);
    }
   }
```

`triggerimpl` defines schedule task at 10PM

you can write Reschedule method as

**RESCHEDULE **

```
class Scheduler {
 private ScheduledFuture future;
    public void schedule (){
     future = managedScheduledExecutorService.schedule(task, triggerimpl);
    }

     public void reschedule (){
     future.cancel(false);
     future = managedScheduledExecutorService.schedule(task, newtriggerimpl);
    }
   }
```

`newtriggerimpl` defines schedule @ 10AM